# Keep just last 100 rows of data in text file

Tags: batch-file

I have this script within a `.bat` file and would like to only keep the most recent 100 lines, at the end of the file.

How do I delete all other rows?

```
@echo off  
REM *DATETIME2.BAT 
REM *Copy date and time to create a new log file 
echo.|date>>"\\spserver\myfolder\dt.tmp" 
echo.|time>>"\\spserver\myfolder\dt.tmp"   
IF NOT EXIST "\\spserver\myfolder\dt.tmp" GOTO Error1 
type "\\spserver\myfolder\dt.tmp"|FIND "current">"\\spserver\myfolder\dt.log" 
rem del "\\spserver\myfolder\dt.tmp"
GOTO End 

:Error1 
Echo.  
Echo There was an error processing the command.  
Echo Unable to find temporary sort file DATETIME2.TMP.  
Echo.  
GOTO End 

:End
```

Comment: Why must everything be done in a .bat script? Can't you make an external program and call it from your batch file?

Comment: @Crono For this particular task I'd like the instructions to be in something simple for the OS to understand. I particularly don't want to use the FileSystemObject library as this bat file is validating a script which uses that library and is having some problems. If you have a simple script + the relevant bat code required then please add suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Call :Tail 100 dt.log tempout.txt
move /y tempout.txt dt.log>nul
exit /b

:Tail <numlines> <FileIn> <FileOut> 
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3,3 delims= " %%l IN (
  `find /c /v "" %2`) DO (call SET find_lc=%%l)
SET /a linenumber=%find_lc%-%1
IF %linenumber% LSS 1 (
  more +0 %2 >> %3
) ELSE (
  more +%linenumber% %2 >> %3
)
```

Comment: +1 thanks for help. I assume that I need to just replace these bits: <numlines> <FileIn> <FileOut> ? What effectively does this do? Does it select the target 100 lines and move them to a new file and then deletes the old file? Or does it use a temporary file - move 100 lines into that, delete all in original file and then move the 100 lines back ? (MS-DOS is very mysterious to me)

Comment: It reads `<numlines>` from the first input file and writes that many lines to a temp file. Then it overwrites the original with the temp. Yes, you just use your own values in the `Call :Tail` line

Comment: ...do you know of any good resources (apart from SO) for learning this language and it's capabilities?

Comment: Here are a couple to get you started. [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/) and [Rob Vanderwoude's Batch Scripting](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchstart.php)